# Which type of join can I use to reproduce these results

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have the following view which contains this data

```
ActivityRecId RegionRecId IsExcluded
1             null        1
2             null        1
3             1           1
3             2           1
4             1           1
5             null        0
```

What I would like to do is join the region table to the view above to get the following records.

```
ActivityRecId RegionRecId IsExcluded
1             null        1
2             null        1
3             1           1
3             2           1
3             3           0
3             4           0
4             1           1
4             2           0
4             3           0
4             4           0
5             null        0
```

The region table has the following columns:

- RegionRecId
- RegionName

Any suggestions. Let me know if you need any other information.

```
--------------------- CORRECT QUESTION ------------------------
ActivityRecId RegionRecId IsExcluded
    1             null        1
    2             null        1
    3             1           1
    3             2           1
    3             3           0
    3             4           0
    4             1           1
    4             2           0
    4             3           0
    4             4           0
    5             1           0
    5             2           0
    5             3           0
    5             4           0
```

If it makes it easier activity 1 and 2 can list all the regions also.

Thanks,

Comment: What does the region table contain? What you've shown looks more like a union than a join.

Comment: The region table just shows the RegionRecId and RegionName

Comment: Doesn't make sense - for what's provided, there's no join between the tables.  You want all the output of the view, and then list the regionrecid from the region table where it doesn't exist in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an SQL Server handy to test this, but would something like

```
select  *
from    myView

union

select  myView.ActivityRecId,
        region.RegionRecId,
        0 as IsExcluded
from    myView cross join region
where   (myView.RegionRecId is not null or myView.IsExcluded = 0)
        and not exists (
            select  null
            from    myView
            where   myView.RegionRecId = region.RegionRecId
        )
```

be what you want?

Comment: This is correct for what I gave you.  Thank you for your answer.  Could you revise the querry to the updated question.

Comment: I hope my revised solution is correct now but once again I'm writing the query without being able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)'s great reference to take a look at for joins.  I think you'd need a Left Outer Join